# Dynamically align width of WPF DataGrid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

There is a WPF `DataGrid` with functionality to dynamically change `FontSize` on Ctrl+MouseWheel event.
It's implemented using Caliburn's cal:Message.Attach functionality:

```
<!-- xaml -->
cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseWheel] = [Action ChangeDataGridFont($eventArgs)]"
```

C# ViewModel:

```
public void ChangeDataGridFont(MouseWheelEventArgs args)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && args != null)
    {
        DataGridFontSize += Math.Sign(args.Delta) * 2;
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

`DataGridFontSize` is a VM property that is bound to `CellStyle` of `DataGrid`.

Upon load widths of columns are aligned with content - Ok:
[image]

If user increases font size then columns width automatically adjusted - Ok:
[image]

However when font size is decreased - columns are not adjusted. See white spaces:
[image]

Is there any way to overcome this effect (in scope of MvvM, if possible)?

**Update:** looks like we need to update Columns width manually when we change `FontSize`.   I can bind Width of column in corresponding Style:

```
<Style x:Key="IdCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding DataContext.ColWidth, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    ....
</Style>
```

And define property:

```
public double ColWidth
{
    get => _colWidth;
    set
    {
        _colWidth = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
    }
}
```

What should I set `ColWidth` to in `DataGridFontSize` setter?

Answer (score 2):

I just added the `Width` for the `DataGridColumn` looks like that works. Try it out.

[image]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MockList"   XPath="/MockObjects/*" >
        <x:XData >
            <MockObjects xmlns="">
                <MockObject  Name="Louis" Type="TTTT" Number="1" />
                <MockObject Name="Joseph" Type="TTTT" Number="2" />
                <MockObject Name="Papineau" Type="ZZZZ" Number="3" />
            </MockObjects>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MockList}}" >
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/MockObjects/MockObject}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Number}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What I see is that all columns widths are fixed in your example. And you don't have columns adjusted to the content at the beginning. Also: when you zoom in eventually "Papineau" does not fit in the column.

Comment: @IgorStack as mentioned you can fix your width to whatever size you desire. I just put `*` to make the `DataGrid` extend all columns to maximum. now you know when you update your font size, update your width in code as well to make it work. my point is you have to adjust the width manually when you mouse scroll. Hope this helps